# Custom Redirect Action Filter Unit Testing

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I've build a Custom Action Filter in order to validate Web Service return parameter. If the parameter is not verified the ActionFilter redirect user to the maintenance page.

Here is my Action Filter

```
public class RequireWSValidation : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public String Controller { get; set; }
    public String Action { get; set; }
    public String ValidationParam { get; set; }

    public RequireWSValidation()
        : this(null, null)
    {
    }

    public RequireWSValidation(string controller, string action)
        : this(controller, action, "WSOk")
    {

    }
    public RequireWSValidation(string controller, string action, string viewDataParam)
    {
        Controller = controller;
        Action = action;
        ValidationParam = viewDataParam;
    }

    public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        if (filterContext.Controller.ViewData[ValidationParam] == null)
        {
            filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(new RouteValueDictionary(new { controller = Controller, action = Action }));
        }
        else if ((Boolean)filterContext.Controller.ViewData[ValidationParam] == false)
        {
            filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(new RouteValueDictionary(new { controller = Controller, action = Action }));
        }
    }
}
```

The Controller :

```
    [RequireWSValidation(Controller = "Home", Action = "Maintenance", ValidationParam = "WSOk")]
    public ActionResult About()
    {
        ViewData["WSOk"] = true;

        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult Maintenance()
    {
        return View();
    }
```

Now I want to Unit Test this ActionFilter Behavior. But the Action "About" always return a ViewResult so i can't test if the ActionFilter redirect user to maintenance page.

My Unit Test :

```
    [Fact]
    public void Should_Redirect_To_Maintenance_On_WS_Error()
    {
        var controller = new HomeController();

        controller.ViewData["WSOk"] = false;

        var result = controller.About() as RedirectToRouteResult;

        Assert.NotNull(result);
        Assert.Equal(result.RouteValues["controller"] as String, "Home");
        Assert.Equal(result.RouteValues["action"] as String, "Maintenance");
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

Action filters are run by the framework (by the action invoker to be precise). In your test, you are calling the action directly, so no additional "magic" is going to happen.

You should probably have two tests - one that checks that the action filter works as expected (check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1057776/how-to-test-action-filters-in-asp-net-mvc) for hints on how to do this), and one that reflects over your controllers and checks which controllers/actions are decorated with your filer.